# Insert data into 'secure' table from shell script

Tags: android, linux, sqlite, shell, adb

hii everyone I am trying to manually set the lock screen to none in a Moto A855(Droid 1) device i have written following shell script for running same but I am getting Exceptions while running the code , i followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1250279/1696704) link for nesting quotes and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16851992/1696704) for inserting data into Sqlite from ADB

```
./adb shell su -c 'mount -o remount,rw /data'
./adb shell su -c 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db "insert into secure values(50,'"'lockscreen.disabled'"',1);"'
```

I am getting following errors while running the script

```
sh: no closing quote
/system/bin/sh: ": not found
```

please help me

thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead, as I think it's a comma issue.

```
./adb shell su -c 'sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db '"'insert into secure values(50,'"'lockscreen.disabled'"',1);'"'
```

Comment: your command's problem is it not able to find closing " or ' in any case.

Comment: thank you so much for replying i have copied your answer and pasted in my script then it is showing Usage: su [options] [LOGIN]

Options:
  -c, --command COMMAND         pass COMMAND to the invoked shell
  -h, --help                    display this help message and exit
  -, -l, --login                make the shell a login shell
  -s, --shell SHELL             use SHELL instead of the default in passwd
  -v, --version                 display version number and exit
  -V                            display version code and exit. this is
                              Superuser.apk