# Can I make this a One-liner solution with ADB or Windows Batch?

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, sqlite, adb

Can I get those three lines in a one-liner solution from windows cmd or in a windows batch file ?

```
adb shell
sqlite3 /data/data/my.package.name/databases/myDb.db
SELECT value1, value2 FROM Table1;
```

I was thinking this is it; but i can't figure how to write it exactly

```
adb shell sqlite3 /data/data/my.package.name/databases/myDb.db | SELECT value1, value2 FROM Table1;
```

Comment: Use the & to concatenate commands onto one line.

Comment: When I use **&&** it shows **sqlite>** but I can't type anyting

Comment: when using the three commands separately, they work normally.

Comment: Did not tell you to use &&. I do not know how your programs work. I just know that if you want all commands on one line at the cmd prompt or a batch file you use the ampersand.

Comment: @AlexP. this is windows cmd not Python

Comment: @AbdelhafidMadoui - the android shell command for `sqlite3` is the same regardless of the scripting language used on the host PC

Comment: I could have linked to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16851992/1778421 instead. Either way your question is a clear duplicate

Comment: yes it's a duplicate for your solution found on http://stackoverflow.com/a/16851992/1778421

Comment: So this question was improperly tagged with the batch-file and cmd tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your phone is rooted (or has engineering build loaded):

```
adb shell "sqlite3 /data/data/my.package.name/databases/myDb.db 'SELECT value1, value2 FROM Table1;'"
```

Because otherwise `shell` user will not have access to `/data/data/my.package.name/`